# Not able overriding variable value from end file using Nunjucks

Tags: html, jinja2, template-engine, nunjucks

I am using Nunjucks as the template engine for my project, where I have the following scenario.

The base file can use the layout and page level variable and generate final HTML.

Base file: base.html

```
<html class="{{htmlClass}}"> .. </html>
```

Layout file: layout.html

```
...
{% extends "html/_layouts/base.html" %}
{% set htmlClass = "class-1" %}
...
```

Page file: page.html

```
...
{% extends "html/_layouts/layout.html" %}
{% set htmlClass = "class-2" %}
...
```

The actual generated HTML file has:

```
<html class="class-1"> .. </html>
```

Expected generated HTML file should have (it should append the page level variable value) :

```
<html class="class-2"> .. </html>
```

Please consider that I do not want to use two separate variables.

Previously I was using the PUG and I was using `block htmlClass` and to override value `append htmlClass` with a variable.

I have tried to find a similar way for Nunjucks, unfortunately, I can't find  `append`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution below.

```
{% set htmlClass = htmlClass | default('class-2') %}
```

Now I am able overriding variable value from end file using Nunjucks.

Comment: Note that this needs to be added to `layout.html`file, so it should have `'class-1'` to be consistent. What it is doing is checking whether child template has already set the variable value, and if it has then instead of overwriting it it's going to use that value.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
{% set htmlClass = "class-2" %}
{% extends "html/_layouts/layout.html" %}
```

instead of:

```
{% extends "html/_layouts/layout.html" %}
{% set htmlClass = "class-2" %}
```

**set** *before* **extends**

Comment: No that won't help, see my answer for the solution.